# Remove everything after space in string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I would like to remove everything after a space in a string.

For example:

```
"my string is sad"
```

should return

```
"my"
```

I've been trying to figure out how to do this using sub/gsub but have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
strsplit("my string is sad"," ")[[1]][1]
```

Comment: a vectorized version to apply across a column of a dataframe would be even cooler

Answer (score 38):

You may use a regex like

```
sub(" .*", "", x)
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/RWncl8/1).

Here, `sub` will only perform a single search and replace operation, the  `.*` pattern will find the first space (since the regex engine is searching strings from left to right) and `.*` matches any zero or more characters (in TRE regex flavor, even including line break chars, beware when using `perl=TRUE`, then it is not the case) as many as possible, up to the string end.

Some variations:

```
sub("[[:space:]].*", "", x) # \s or [[:space:]] will match more whitespace chars
sub("(*UCP)(?s)\\s.*", "", x, perl=TRUE) # PCRE Unicode-aware regex
stringr::str_replace(x, "(?s) .*", "")   # (?s) will force . to match any chars
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/xmJiyY).

Comment: For what it's worth I recommend trying the `sub("(*UCP)(?s)\\s.*", "", x, perl=TRUE)` variation. Pleased to find this works where other variations might fail.

Answer (score 12):

or, substitute everything behind the first space to nothing:

```
gsub(' [A-z ]*', '' , 'my string is sad')
```

And with numbers:

```
gsub('([0-9]+) .*', '\\1', c('c123123123 0320.1'))
```

Comment: Watch out, the top example can't remove a period!

Answer (score 6):

[Stringr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html) is your friend.

```
library(stringr)
word("my string is sad", 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it with a regex:

```
gsub('([A-z]+) .*', '\\1', 'my string is sad')
```